# How to populate initial values of form from queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `FormView` with a `get_initial` method which I am trying to use to populate the form. I am trying to get the `EmployeeType`s of the `receiver` of the `memo` as values in the form.

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(NotificationView, self).get_initial()
        users = Memo.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).values('receiver__employee_type')
        initial['receiving_groups'] = users
        return initial
```

There are 2 issues here..

1. This returns a Queryset which looks like: `<QuerySet [{'receiver__employee_type': 'Bartender'}, {'receiver__employee_type': 'Supervisor'}]>` when I really need the fields in the form to be the `EmployeeType` itself.
2. Most importantly - the form isn't even rendering these fields.

Here is the form just in case:

```
class MemoNotificationForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'receiving_groups'
        ]
    receiving_groups = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

How do I populate the fields of the form?

EDIT:

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    receiver = models.ManyToManyField(EmployeeType, related_name='memos_receiver')

class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    """Stores user employee type."""
    employee_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        unique=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `Meta` on a `forms.Form` doesn't do anything, this is used for `ModelForm`s

If `receiving_groups` should be choices of `EmployeeType` then it should be a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](http://ModelMultipleChoiceField)

```
class MemoNotificationForm(forms.Form):
    receiving_groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        EmployeeType.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

Then you should be passing instances, or a queryset of the model in the initial

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(NotificationView, self).get_initial()
        initial['receiving_groups'] = EmployeeType.objects.filter(memo__id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return initial
```

EDIT:
As a `ModelForm` this could look like so

```
class MemoNotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Memo
        fields = ('receiver', )
```

View:

```
class NotificationView(FormView);
    form_class = MemoNotificationForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NotificationView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = get_object_or_404(Memo, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Good answer and thank you. I didn't realize the `get_initial` method overrides the form qs. If this is the case then should I be using a `ModelForm` if only that specific model's data is needed and a generic form when I want to use several models?

Comment: In most cases using a `ModelForm` takes a lot of manual field definition away so is preferable

Comment: Also, this doesn't exactly work because `EmployeeType` does not have an attribute of `memo`. But I get the point :)

Comment: I get that the ModelForm is easier and preferred but I am trying to see *why and when* I should use one or the other. If you could help me there...

Comment: If you are creating or editing an instance of a model then you should nearly always be using a `ModelForm`

Comment: If your form is not creating/editing an instance of a model that is when you should be using a `Form`

Comment: Gotcha, so with what i am doing with the current form then a generic form fits the case.. Also, would you mind updating your answer so I can see what it would look like..

Comment: How it would look as a ModelForm?

Comment: I wasn't asking how it would look but rather when to use it but I get it now :) Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

While @lain Shelvington is correct in the process he used to produce the form results, I had to do a little editing to make the code operate correctly...

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(NotificationView, self).get_initial()
        receivers = Memo.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('receiver')
        initial['receiving_groups'] = EmployeeType.objects.filter(employee_type=receivers)
        return initial
```